# Is it possible to convert a .shp file to .gml?

Tags: shapefile, gml

Is it possible to convert a shapefile to a gml file?
If so, how and using what tools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, using the command line `ogr2ogr` tool.

For example, given a "roads.shp" file, you could convert it using the following:

```
ogr2ogr -f GML roads.gml roads.shp
```

`ogr2ogr` provides a [large array of options](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html), so you might want to review them prior to executing. You can also use the tool to create only a subset of the input data and also reproject the output.